# Get Identity of Tables in a Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, identity

Is there a way to get an ID for a Table in a Mysql Database?

If I use the `show tables` Statement I get a lot of Informations about the Tables in my Database, but there is no Identifier. How can i get the actual ID of the Tables?

Comment: What do you mean by ID or Identifier

Comment: I would like to Identify the Tables of a Database by an ID, and thought, that there must be already an internal Handling, that could provide me an ID per Table. Example: table1 has ID 1, table2 has ID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT table_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', -1) as table_name FROM  `INNODB_SYS_TABLES` where name like  'database_name%';
```

for example, show IDs of all table in `mysql` database:

```
SELECT table_id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', -1) as table_name FROM  `INNODB_SYS_TABLES` where name like  'mysql%';
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use **OOP** method for calling ID in Mysql database

Comment: How do you mean that? Could you provide some more Information about your answer?